# MongoDb optimistic concurency with upsert

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, upsert

I have a service that process a stream of messages and persist them in MongoDb collection.
For simplicity sake let assume message is as following:

```
{ 
  id=1,
  sequenceNumber = 1000,
  data = "some data" 
}
```

The requirements are to store only the **last** message per `id` by `sequenceNumber`.

SequenseNumber is guaranteed to be unique incrementing value.

The important part - this is multi-node service and processing several hundreds messages per second.

This is what been done in current implementation:

```
var existing = await GetAsync(document.Id); // gets document by Id or null if not found

if (existing == null) ||  // new document
   (existing.SequenceNumber < document.SequenceNumber) //out of order update
{
    var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", BsonValue.Create(document.Id));
    await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(
        replacement: document,
        filter: filter, 
        options: new ReplaceOptions{ IsUpsert = true} );
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite this "upsert" to single atomic operation?
In a nutshell: insert document if not exist or update if newer than existing

UPDATE: Although I am using .Net here, any implementation is welcomed

Comment: Just to be clear, if the record with the _id exists you want to update it, but only if sequence number on the new record is a higher number than what is on the database record.  If the _id does not exist, you want to create the record.  If the _id exists, but the sequenceNumber is the same or higher you do not want to take any action.  Correct?

Comment: @barrypicker, yes absolutely correct

Comment: So the problem is you need 3 states (insert, update, do nothing) but the upsert option only handles 2 states (insert, update).  If the filter criteria of an upsert is not matched it attempts an insert, else an update.  Since you need a third state (do nothing) you must first query the document to evaluate if you shall indeed do something.  For this reason an update with upsert will not work.  You can achieve atomicity via a database transaction.  This causes the query to take longer and can cause database contention.

Comment: ... and, by the way, MongoDB does not have a 'select for update' option.  There is a work-around solution if you are interested in pursuing a 'select-for-update' transaction implementation.

Comment: @barrypicker, my concern is the concurrency, so the Read -> Evaluate -> UpsertIfNeeded  approach cannot guarantee that state of the record in db is stays the same between read and write.

Comment: Right - that is why a database transaction would wrap multiple actions into an atomic submission.  But the read part of the transaction is the tricky part because MongoDB does not (natively) support 'select-for-update'.  You must tweak that bit to allow the transaction to block updates to the records you are reading while in the middle of a transaction.

Comment: Here is an article by Renato describing how to work around the fact MongoDB does not have native "select-for-update".   https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-select--for-update-inside-mongodb-transactions

Comment: I cannot apply this work around as the data comes from third party source and I cannot alter it in any ways.

Comment: So, the workaround can be applied such that there is no modifications to the existing persisted data.  The modifications would be in a transaction that is uncommitted, but blocking others from modification until rollback or commit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236372/discussion-between-barrypicker-and-michael-d).

Comment: db.data.update({"$and":[{"id":2},{"seqNo":{"$gt":2}}]},{$set:{"test":123,_id:2}},{upsert:true});

- try similar query .... it will insert if no entry is there,,,, update if entry is there and seq number is greater ... throw exception if greater seq number exists .. Since inserts wont work with same _id field